# How to reuse code in Spock tests

Tags: spock, geb

I'm writing Spock + Geb based tests for web site testing. Web site is used to create offers and later various actions can be performed on them (confirm, reject, withdraw). I already created working scenario for creating an offer. But now when I came to the point that I need to implement scenarios for various combinations of actions I would like to be able to reuse "create offer" in these other scenarios. Unfortunately I'm not able to find any example or to think good way how to do it. Could someone give me any ideas about that?

*By the way I need to perform actions in predefined sequence so I'm using **Stepwise** annotation on my specifications.*

Answer (score 1):

## Single Page Actions:

It's hard to say without seeing examples of your code, but one way of doing this is to define the methods for your actions (confirm, reject, withdraw) as simple methods in your Page class:

```
class ActionsPage extends Page {

  static content = { 
    //Page content here
  }

  def confirm (){
    //Code to perform confirm action on the page
  }

  def reject (){
    //Code to perform reject action on the page
  }
```

Then in your Specification class you can do

```
def "Test confirm action"(){
  when: "we go to the actions pages"
  to ActionsPage

  and: "we perform a confirm action"
  confirm()

 then: "something happens"
 //Code which checks the confirmation worked 
}
```

This works because Geb uses Groovy's method missing stuff to find the name of the method on the current page called "confirm ()", and will execute that code.

## Multiple Page Actions:

If the actions are complicated and involve navigating to several pages, it is best to create an abstract base class for your tests which need to perform the actions:

```
//Not @Stepwise
abstract class BaseActionsSpec extends Specification {

  //Note: don't use Spock when/then blocks in these methods as they are not feature methods
  protected void confirm(){
    //Code to perform multi-page action
  }

  protected void reject(){
    //Code to perform multi-page action 
  }
}
```

Then the extending classes:

```
@Stepwise
class ConfirmActionSpec extends BaseActionsSpec{

      def "Test confirm action"(){
        when: "we go to the actions pages"
        to ActionsPage

        and: "we perform a confirm action"
        confirm() //calls method in super class

        then: "something happens"
       //Code which checks the confirmation worked 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually these actions are not so simple but they consist of flow of actions in different web pages. So that's why I would like to implement them as separate specifications and later have possibility somehow to include them into another specifications. Is it possible to add new features into specification using extension?

Comment: Ok, this solution is only suitable for single page actions, so I will add another solution which will work for you

Comment: By the way, the @Stepwise annotation doesn't support inheritance that well, so if you have features in a super class, the order they are executed in with regards to the subclass's features is not defined. I had to write a custom Spock extension to get the behaviour (proprietary code though sorry) that you want here. I recommend just moving the action code out of the features and into helper methods as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I would like to have fully reusable features or even specifications but understand that there are no such capabilities. So will try to live with helper classes and inheritance.

Comment: How about using traits? We often use traits to inject common behavior and helper methods to our Spock tests.

Comment: @loteq thank you! With traits my source code looks better.